# Expo React-Native App doesn't work when run as a standalone APK

Tags: react-native, expo

My Expo-based React Native App works without a problem when run in the Expo tool but gave the following errors when built as an APK to be installed and run standalone.

A series of white screens keep flipping before the blue screen comes up.

Here are my App.JSON and Package.JSON files

[Package.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sBBwWXNnNoCCn34EXPUBgGXI7OKk5Xm2)
[App.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18Q5IFpB5X_Z7D-fDTErjK0b7KJkVzfBI)

And here are the screen capturing the error message.

[image: Flipping Screen]
[image: Blue Screen]
[image: Error Messages]

Comment: Have you ejected into native? using yarn eject?

Comment: No I didn't. Sorry, am new to Expo development, could you give me more directions?

Comment: There are two ways to create react native application, Either by using create-react-native-app or using react-native init. what you used?

Comment: I used create-react-native-app

Comment: My apk was created with the expo publish: android command.

Comment: Ok that means, you are now running the app inside expo am i right?

Comment: Dont do like this.

Comment: Yes, the app has no problem running in expo. but when I attempted to publish with expo publish: android, the error above is observed.

Comment: For development purpose you can use expo, but for build dont use exp publish.

Comment: What will be a good way to generate a workable APK file to run standalone in a mobile device?

Comment: Ok wait i will post that in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem. The 'eth-lightwallet' library works perfectly within the Expo development tool but when I build into an APK, it just made the white screen turns up with no meaningful error messages.

The solution is to replace it with a pure web3js implementation.

This may be useful if you are developing a mobile app for Ethereum.

Comment: Hi Jackson, how did you debug your problem?

Comment: You mean how I managed to find out that it's eth-lightwallet causing the white screen? I removed libraries one at a time until the white screen comes up. Probably the worst way to troubleshoot but this was the only option available to me as there were no meaningful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two ways to create a React Native application

1. create-react-native-app (CRNA)
2. react-native init

As you stated in comment section, You created your project using CRNA

CRNA will gave you some form of solid project structure, which is really useful for beginners to get started with react native, you code the app with pure javascript and the app will work inside Expo.

Now if you want to take build and run as a standalone apk for android,
There are two methods

1. You can run command: exp publish:android
2. You can eject your app from expo

Dont use exp publish for standalone apks,

You can use second method:

To eject your app:

First if you dont use any expo apis inside your apps, it is very easy to eject and build as a stand alone apk.

just do yarn eject

This will gave you some instructions and follow that.
After that your CRNA project structure will be converted into react-native init project structure, now you will be able to see "Android" and "iOS" folders inside your application

To take build Run: connect your phone with USB debugging ON and react-native run android.

That's all.

Comment: In my case, I used expo apis. How else can i do this? I attempted to eject and chose the "ExpoKit: I'll create or log in with an Expo account to use React Native and the Expo SDK." option. Now it just shows "An Expo account is required to proceed" and hangs there.

Comment: Yes create or login expo account then proceed.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I open the ejected project in Android Studio and tried to run in both emulator and as an APK, but they just stopped.